# Yeoman setup for client + server project

Tags: javascript, node.js, scaffolding, yeoman

I'm developing a framework based on "[Scalable Javascript Application Architecture](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/scalable-javascript-application-architecture)" with modules that should be able to run both on the server (node) as well as the client.

I'm looking for a good project set-up/bootstrap where client and server-side could be developed/build/tested separately while still making use of some shared resources such as the mentioned modules.

I like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) for a clientside setup, and it seems that yeoman is extending it's reach to include scaffolds for server-side stuff although this is still somewhat experimental.

However, to this day I 've yet to find a project setup that combines server + client setup as described above.

Any pointers, github test project, etc. highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this experimental branch the Yeoman team are working on:

http://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/tree/express-stack

Comment: Thanks, but I've already got a framework like that working for the client. Was asking for a setup that would have best practices for scaffolding/ dir structure / build / test, etc.

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry about that. You might want to take a look at this experimental branch the Yeoman team are working on: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/tree/express-stack

Comment: Ah yes, that's more what I meant. I'll let this question linger for a while to see what more pops up. If nothing, I'll accept in a couple of days. Thanks. (BTW: might want to update your answer with your comment)